# The trio worked together

Tags: riddle

Who are they?

A bad winter day

I look out the windows

All roads frozen solid

How to get back to the office?

(Help, need help)

Then it happened

> I summoned the trio
>
> Two came from the southwest
>
> One from the northeast
>
> They all got together
>
> Showed me different ways
>
> To get back to work

I AM BACK IN THE OFFICE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems on this bad winter day you were

> using Microsoft Windows and Office applications were frozen.

To get back in the office you

> pressed  **Ctrl** and **Alt** keys from the southwest and **Del** from the northeast positions on the keyboard. Then used Task Manager to stop the stuck programs and got back into MS Office!

Comment: Perfectly solved.

Answer (score 2):

Could be

> You used a snowmobile to get back to the office.

Because

> Depending on your route to the office, a snowmobile has two sleds to steer and one track to push. Two from the SW and one from the NE. For example:
>  [image]
>  Definitely a different way to get back to work on a bad winter day!

Comment: There are a few key words in the puzzle that are hints.